# Remove Visualizer Menu from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

I installed an extension for Visual Studio 2017, but it has left the menus behind.

[[image: Visualizer Menu1]

Does anyone know how to remove these as the author is not responding.

Any help would be great, thanks in advance

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Does the author upload it to github as an open source project? You can modify the code to disable it then rebuild and install it.

If not, you can only wait for the author's response.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I should have posted back that you can remove it from `{documents}\Visual Studio 20xx\Visualizers\` folder.

Thanks for the reply and sorry to have wasted your time.